# Run Async Fn in a Sync Fn in an Async Context

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I have a setup that can be boiled down to:

```
fn work() {
    // some sync stuff
    // work2()
}

async fn work2() {
    // some async stuff
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    work();
}
```

How do I execute `work2` from within `work`? I've tried using `tokio::block_on` which gives the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Cannot start a runtime from within a runtime. This 
happens because a function (like `block_on`) attempted to block the current 
thread while the thread is being used to drive asynchronous tasks.'
```

Does this mean I have to use another thread? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I assume you can modify the implementation (but not the signature) of `work()`, but not `work2()` and `main()`? Is the stuff done by `work2()` related to the async stuff in `main()` in any way?

Comment: Yeah, it's a sync closure that calls an async initializer. `work2` can't be moved into main unfortunately.

Comment: The sad answer is "you cannot". The realistic answer is "there are workarounds, but they're very bad".